# What to do when OP refuses to approve (correct) edit suggestions

Tags: support

In this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10555/12804), I recommended to [edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18226) the title. Now, without going into the arguments, it can be said that the OP is refusing to be open-minded. Even though he knows his question title is improper (as can be seen from the question description), he is vehement not to amend it.

What a normal user can do in such a situation?

**UPDATE**
Since, this question was taken personally, I feel to put my personal thoughts here (which I did not intend to do for a meta question):

1. I did not even touch the question description.
2. No matter they were lesbian or not, they were co-wives.

Comment: @Ankit Sharma: Request not to take this question as a personal attack.

Comment: I just want to save my question's original intent.

Comment: What does "open mindedness" have to do with this question or edit?

Comment: @NogShine There's no short answer. You have to go through the discussions (arguments). :D

Comment: I read all the comments. The edit changes the intent of the author. It is not allowed to change the intent. Rejecting an edit which does it is not close mindedness. You probably missed the part after the comma. If you read it completely, then you'll understand. Lesbianism means attraction (may be sexually) between two females. They need not to be married. If there's no lesbianism in Hinduism, then answer saying that but please don't edit the question.

Comment: @NogShine Can you join the chat room? Besides, I don't see why this issues should matter here. This is a meta question, so you should comment something like, "Review your thoughts", or "Leave OP as he wants". "If there's no lesbianism in Hinduism... <blah> <blah>"  should be off-topic for this question. I

Answer (score 6):

Your edit was rejected due to this reason:

> **clearly conflicts with author's intent**
>
> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

For the full list of rejection reasons see [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239950/187039).

You said:

> Even though he [OP] *knows* his question title is improper...

How do you *know* this for sure? Did you check with OP before attempting to edit? Maybe he wasn't sure when he posted the question. His initial assumptions could be wrong. He may have changed his opinion after an answer was posted. But what's the point of "correcting" the question now? Should a question contain only true statements or reasonable assumptions? What if your version of truth is different from OP's?

Your specific edit may even be rejected due to another reason:

> **no improvement whatsoever**
>
> This edit fails to make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either **completely superfluous** or actively harm readability.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are not editing a question, you are changing the meaning of question according to your own comfort and believes. And you are the being conservative here and censoring others what they can and can't say.

If you have points to prove the question premises is wrong then challenge it by giving proper sourced answer not forced edits.

To make it clear, my question was "Bhagiratha was raised by a lesbian couple?"  and you want to change it to co-wives. Both word have different meaning.

[Lesbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesbian) :

> A lesbian is a homosexual woman who is romantically or sexually attracted to other women.

[co-wife](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-wife)

> In a polygamous marriage, another wife of a woman's husband

I am not asking about [polygamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamy) here. If you have question about polygamy among bhagiratha's parents, then ask separate question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69727/discussion-on-answer-by-ankit-sharma-what-to-do-when-op-refuses-to-approve-corr).